# Java Matching parenthesis

Tags: java, stack

Been working on this all day there seems to be a compilation error. I need it to output Arithmetic Expression: has matched symbols when {25 + (3 – 6) * 8}  is the output(it does this correctly) but when I input a mismatching one like }{25 + (3 – 6) I get an Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException error

```
import java.util.*;

public class Comparison {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();



        System.out.print("Please enter arithmetic expression: For example, the expression {25 + (3 – 6) * 8} ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        String capture = input.nextLine();
//           String[] pieces = capture.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < capture.length(); i++) {
            char p = capture.charAt(i);
            if (p == '{' || p == '(' || p == '[' ) {
                stack.push(p);
            }
            char r = stack.peek();
     if (p == '}' || p == ')' || p == ']')
     {

        if (p == '}' && r == '{' || p == ')' && r == '(' || p == ']' && r == '['){
          stack.pop();
        System.out.print("Arithmetic Expression: has matched symbols.");
        }

                 else {
        System.out.print("Arithmetic  Expression: has mismatched symbols.");

              } 


      }


    }



}


   }
```

Comment: The error message makes a lot of sense... It's equivalent of a `NullPointerExcepion` in the sense that nothing exists on the stack but you're trying to execute a read/pop operation on it. You can `try-catch` this exception and on the `catch` you know that the input is bad because it doesn't have properly enclosed brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if stack is currently empty at this point:

```
 if (stack.size()==0){
    // message when the stack is empty: parenthesis not closed
     break;
 }
 char r = stack.peek();
 if (p == '}' || p == ')' || p == ']')
 {

    if (p == '}' && r == '{' || p == ')' && r == '(' || p == ']' && r == '['){
      stack.pop();
    System.out.print("Arithmetic Expression: has matched symbols.");
    }

             else {
    System.out.print("Arithmetic  Expression: has mismatched symbols.");

          } 


  }


}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest just a change While **`POPING`**

as

> if (p == '}' && r == '{' || p == ')' && r == '(' || p == ']' && r ==
>   '[' **&& stack.size()>0**)

that's it!